# How to handle bad HTTP request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an exception in my Rails app that I don't know how to catch. Here is the stacktrace:

```
ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding (%26%20allcfgconv%20-C%20voip%20-c%20-o%20-%20../../../../../var/tmp/voip.cfg%20%2)
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:901 in "decode_www_form_component"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:42 in "unescape"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:94 in "block (2 levels) in parse_nested_query"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:94 in "map"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:94 in "block in parse_nested_query"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:93 in "each"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:93 in "parse_nested_query"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:373 in "parse_query"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:188 in "GET"
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb:225 in "params"
/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:12 in "call"
```

The problem is that the request does not hit the code of the app and the exception is thrown by the frameworks. It seems to be a sort of an attack.

How can I prevent it to happen ?

Comment: please provide the input data to parse

Comment: The only thing I have is the URL sent to the server:
`http://yannick.example.com:3000/cgi-bin/webcm?getpage=../html/menus/menu2.html&var:lang=%26%20allcfgconv%20-C%20voip%20-c%20-o%20-%20../../../../../var/tmp/voip.cfg%20%2`

Comment: In dev, Webrick just says that that it is a bad URI: [2014-11-21 11:47:42] ERROR bad URI `/cgi-bin/webcm?getpage=../html/menus/menu2.html&var:lang=%26%20allcfgconv%20-C%20voip%20-c%20-o%20-%20../../../../../var/tmp/voip.cfg%20%2'.

However in production, I get an exception

Comment: is it the post request? and ajax or not?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Ruby 2.1.3 Rails 4.1.6 and yes it is a GET request

Answer (score 0):

I get these attacks too.  It's very frustrating because they trigger automated messages that appear to the whole team, including some non-technical people.  They become worried because, "oh no, something is broken in production!"

What I did (and I hope someone suggests a better solution) is to make custom entries in routes.rb file for each new kind of attack, which directs it to a controller that does nothing.